# How to add the popular tags block

Tags: magento-1.8, blocks, tags

I was going through the level up video tutorials about magento, in that they are using the sample data and are making a theme in which one thing they do is shift the block from one side to the other but i do not have this block, so how to put this block into my magento site?

Answer (score 2):

Add below code in your layout files,

```
<block type="tag/popular" name="tags_popular" template="tag/popular.phtm">
 <action method="setTemplate"><template>tag/popular.phtml</template></action>
</block>
```

Answer (score 1):

In the default theme you can look into `app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/tag.xml` and see the following code:

```
<default>
    <!-- Mage_Tag -->
    <reference name="left">
        <block type="tag/popular" name="tags_popular" template="tag/popular.phtml"/>
    </reference>

</default>
```

This will add the block `tag/popular` but do note that this will only display if there are tags in the system.

```
protected function _toHtml()
{
    if (count($this->getTags()) > 0) {
        return parent::_toHtml();
    }
    return '';
}
```